# Using brackets inside a character class in a regular expression

Tags: bash, sed

I have a string:

```
['A', 'B']
```

I need to remove all `,`, `[`, and `]` characters. The final result should be

```
'A' 'B'
```

Below is a list of everything I tried, and the results

**Commands I tried**

```
user@vm:~$ echo "['A', 'B']" | sed -r 's/[\[\],]//g'
['A', 'B']

user@vm:~$ echo "['A', 'B']" | sed -r 's/[[],]//g'  # unescaped
['A', 'B']

user@vm:~$ echo "['A', 'B']" | sed -r 's/[\[\]]//g'  # removed ","
['A', 'B']

user@vm:~$ echo "['A', 'B']" | sed -r 's/[,]//g'  #removed "[" and "]"
['A' 'B']

user@vm:~$ echo "['A', 'B']" | sed -r 's/[[,]//g'  # removed "]"
'A' 'B']
```

*Obviously*, none of them worked. However, these commands did:

```
user@vm:~$ echo "['A', 'B']" | sed -r 's/[],[]//g'
'A' 'B'

user@vm:~$ echo "['A', 'B']" | sed -r 's/[][,]//g'
'A' 'B'
```

Why did this work? Differences between commands above and below:

- The `[`, `]` are not escaped
- The order is different (] before [)

Why does the order matter?

Comment: check `man sed` or `info sed` (gnu sed)... it might be mentioned... for ex: see https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Character-Classes-and-Bracket-Expressions.. `to make the ‘]’ character a list item, you must put it first`

Comment: An unescaped `]` must be placed at the first place in a character class in BRE or extended regex.

Comment: Skip `sed` altogether, use `tr` instead.

Comment: `sed -r 's/[\x5d,\x5b]//g'`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From `info sed` (see also https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Character-Classes-and-Bracket-Expressions)

> A leading '^' reverses the meaning of LIST, so that it matches any
>   single character *not* in LIST.  To include ']' in the list, make
>   it the first character (after the '^' if needed), to include '-'
>   in the list, make it the first or last; to include '^' put it
>   after the first character.

And as mentioned in comments, `tr` is better suited

```
$ echo "['A', 'B']" | tr -d '[],'
'A' 'B'
```